# Oracle SQL INNER JOIN and Count(*)=1 doesn't get rid of duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, count, inner-join

My original Oracle SQL Query (at end of post) outputs

[image]

but I want it to output this

[image]

I was advised to use  `INNER JOIN` to remove any duplicates.

This didn't work.

Then I was advised to use `HAVING COUNT(*)=1`

This *partially works*

Instead of there being 3 or 4 duplicates, there is at most 2 duplicates.

Any ideas?

Original SQL Query

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(MIN(I.INCIDENTID))                  AS "Incident ID",
          MIN(I.CREATIONDATE)                      AS "Creation Date",
          TO_CHAR(I.CREATIONDATE,'MM-DD-YYYY')     AS "Date",
          TRIM(MO.DOMAINUSERNAME)                  AS "Login ID",  
          TRIM(M.MESSAGESUBJECT)                   AS "Email Subject"
   FROM  INCIDENT I 
   JOIN  MESSAGE M
   ON M.MESSAGEID = I.MESSAGEID
   JOIN   MESSAGEORIGINATOR MO
   ON     M.MESSAGEORIGINATORID = MO.MESSAGEORIGINATORID           
   GROUP BY TO_CHAR(I.CREATIONDATE,'MM-DD-YYYY'),
            TRIM(MO.DOMAINUSERNAME),
            TRIM(M.MESSAGESUBJECT)
```

Identical query, except I added `INNER JOIN` and `HAVING COUNT(*)=1`

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(MIN(I.INCIDENTID))                  AS "Incident ID",
          MIN(I.CREATIONDATE)                      AS "Creation Date",
          TO_CHAR(I.CREATIONDATE,'MM-DD-YYYY')     AS "Date",
          TRIM(MO.DOMAINUSERNAME)                  AS "Login ID",  
          TRIM(M.MESSAGESUBJECT)                   AS "Email Subject"
   FROM  INCIDENT I 
   INNER JOIN  MESSAGE M
   ON M.MESSAGEID = I.MESSAGEID
   INNER JOIN   MESSAGEORIGINATOR MO
   ON     M.MESSAGEORIGINATORID = MO.MESSAGEORIGINATORID           
   GROUP BY TO_CHAR(I.CREATIONDATE,'MM-DD-YYYY'),
            TRIM(MO.DOMAINUSERNAME),
            TRIM(M.MESSAGESUBJECT)
HAVING COUNT(*)=1
```

Comment: Inner join and join are same, so other than having count(*) = 1 there is no difference between the 2 queries. Also, it would be helpful if you show sample input data. [Read here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) some tips about asking SQL questions.

Comment: @Rohit I blanked out sensitive data intentionally, and left `Incident ID` and `Date` in full view

Comment: You dont have to include real data, you can make up the fake values.

Answer (score 1):

use row_number()

```
  with cte as (  SELECT TO_CHAR(I.INCIDENTID))                  AS "Incident ID",
              (I.CREATIONDATE)                      AS "Creation Date",
              TO_CHAR(I.CREATIONDATE,'MM-DD-YYYY')     AS "Date",
              TRIM(MO.DOMAINUSERNAME)                  AS "Login ID",  
              TRIM(M.MESSAGESUBJECT)                   AS "Email Subject",
              row_number() over(partition by TO_CHAR(I.CREATIONDATE,'MM-DD-YYYY'),
            TRIM(MO.DOMAINUSERNAME), TRIM(M.MESSAGESUBJECT) order by TO_CHAR(I.INCIDENTID)),I.CREATIONDATE) rn 
       FROM  INCIDENT I 
       JOIN  MESSAGE M
       ON M.MESSAGEID = I.MESSAGEID
       JOIN   MESSAGEORIGINATOR MO
       ON     M.MESSAGEORIGINATORID = MO.MESSAGEORIGINATORID 
) select * from cte where rn=1
```

Comment: Hello @zaynul-abadin-tuhin I will try this. For some reason, PowerBI is not recognizing this. Will adjust the syntax and keep you updated.